# Refresh single div based on time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload, partial-page-refresh

I'm using a Wordpress widget that displays the latest Forex currency information however the latest data is only loaded when the page is refreshed. I've noticed a few methods of refreshing a single div using jQuery and java but I haven't found a working solution for what I'm looking for.

The div ID is #sm_widget-2 and I'm looking for a 12 second delay before refreshing/reloading.

If anyone can shed some light on this for me I would be very greatful!

Comment: That is a very general question and maybe off-topic for stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Why didnt it work? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
setInterval(function()
{
  $('#sm_widget-2').load(document.URL +  ' #sm_widget-2');
}, 120000);
```